# Linux Mint on Lenovo E14 brightness cannot be adjusted

Tags: linux-mint, brightness

I'm new to this world. So the <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> function keys basically don't work. I tried a few online solutions regarding changing grub, no luck. I found out that there is no file in `/sys/class/backlight/`, no `intel_backlight` per se.

```
jing@jing-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-2:~$ sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/platform::mute/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/platform::mute/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinklight/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinklight/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::power/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::power/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::standby/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::standby/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinkvantage/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinkvantage/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness_hw_changed
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/platform::micmute/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/platform::micmute/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::scrolllock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/leds/phy0-led/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/leds/phy0-led/max_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/hw_changes_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
/sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/brightness_enable
/sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/brightness_mode
/sys/module/i915/parameters/invert_brightness
```

Comment: Did you try searching via `find /sys -name 'backlight'`?

Comment: @FelixJN: this was what i  got:  /sys/module/video/parameters/disable_backlight_sysfs_if
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_dpcd_backlight

Answer (score 1):

Until you find the proper backlight option, you may adjust the gamma values via `xrandr`. Use `xrandr --query` to get the name of the display from the first entry on second line, e.g. `eDP`, then set the brightness via

```
xrandr --output eDP --bightness 0.5
```

Values go from 0 ("black screen") to 1 ("normal") to, I think 255 ("why would one do that?")

Comment: hmm it says: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*

Comment: @FelixJN `xrands --query` should be `xrandr --query`

Comment: @JeremyBoden TY, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to update the kernel (to 5.8) to be able to recognize the graphic driver. That solves the problem. Thanks guys for suggestions.